# GFI Outlet wiring a new outlet

Tags: electrical, wiring

Your diagram is excellent, I had 1 question, attaching new wires to existing GFI, attach to screw on side of outlet, or tie into nut back in box that has 3 wires tied into already ?

Thanks Bob

Comment: What diagram? If it is a diagram from a particular question or answer, include a link to it so we all know what you are talking about.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Exchange. Closing because this looks like you are trying to carry on a dialog with some unknown entity. SE is a Q&A site, so we have different policies from forums.  If you have an actual question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 1):

A GFCI receptacle normally has two sets of hot/neutral screws **Line** and **Load**. The incoming power is connected to **Line**. If you want to have additional receptacles using the protection of this GFCI then they need to be connected to **Load**. One either side (incoming *Line* possibly shared with other **non-protected** receptacles, or *Load* connecting to multiple **protected** receptacles), if you have more than one set of wires (plus the GFCI receptacle itself) then you should use a pigtail - a short piece of wire with a wire nut to connect to multiple wires. Electrical tape is **NOT** normally needed, except sometimes around the screws as an extra protection against shorts. If wire nuts are so loose that you need electrical tape then you are using the wrong size of wire nuts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you're adding a new receptacle to the "load" side or the "line" side of the gfi. Line side means you're daisy chaining or sending the line from the breaker to another receptacle or different room, ect.  The load side is for using the gfi to protect other receptacles in the same area like in a kitchen c-top,the outlets near the sink on either side may all be on the gfi load side.  Therefore, if any of the outlets trip the gfi, they'll  all trip and you'll need to reset the gfi button.  Try not to "crowd" any screw terminals on the gfi. A wire nut connection behind the device is ok but you can make it a lil crowded inside the junction box when you have 3 or more other devices being fed from this jbox the gfi is in.  Use electrical tape around your gfi terminals and those wire nut junctions to make for connection integrity.